# grails - ways to set up a replicated site?

Tags: grails

I've got a need where each user can customize their own page on a replicated site.  In grails it seems the most straightforward way to do this is:

```
somedomain.com/someController/JohnDoe
```

spelling out a controller, except this forces folks to type in a longer domain name, versus something like

```
somedomain.com/JohnDoe
```

Using sub-domains may be another approach, however they would need to be created automatically, i.e. when someone joins.

Can you please clarify the main ways Grails supports this kind of requirement/need (replicated site), and some of the pros/cons of each?

Thanks, Ray

---

Edit:  Per Tomasz's edit below, the simplest course of action isn't clear.  If you have insights on this please do share.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [UrlMappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) in grails. You need to declare:

```
"/$username?" {
    controller = 'someController'
    action = 'user'
}
```

It redirects to someController, action `user` and optional variable called `username`.

This solution has one catch. Every one level path you visit passes this rule and takes you to `someController`. You cannot go to `somedomain.com/books` because it passes rule above and it follows you to `someController#user` with `params['username']='books'`. Then you can't use default actions. But if you decide that all your other paths have at least one slash, e.g. `/books/list` then you can follow this solution

Edit: I was wrong. It doesn't work as I've expected. I thought that UrlMappings are applied in order they are defined. That's not true, as explained [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Url-mappings-referencing-a-controller-td2132851.html). Even worse - it's not documented ([GRAILS-6246](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6246)). Most specific explanation comes from Peter Ledbrook :

> It uses a specificity algorithm, so the most specific match should apply

You must experiment then. I suggest you use safest solution and stick with `/user/username` solution.

Comment: Hi Tomasz - nice to hear from you -- this sounds like a good solution.  Are there any security issues you can think of?  For other paths that have at least one slash, this would still allow for default actions though, is that correct?

Comment: @Ray I don't find any special security issues with this solution. It allows default actions with at least one slash.

Comment: Tomasz - thanks for posting / clarifying.  I'll investigate further.  It would definitely be nice to be able to give users a very simple domain to use.  It seems other technologies make this possible, so I  imagine Grails must somehow.